# How to add custom forms in FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery-plugins, calendar, fullcalendar

I have created forms in HTML (shown image below), and I want to integrate this form in [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). This form will show when I wanted to add new event. Can you give me some idea?  If possible, can I do this without modifying the plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the form in a lightbox and show it, when the user clicks on a day. Fullcalendar provides an event for this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/

Edit: Or what exactly do you mean by integrate?